# Ubuntu starting up to black screen - but only sometimes

Tags: grub2, 20.04, uefi, startup, bios

**Problem description:**
Often, during startup a black screen appears and the startup process freezes (about 80% of times). At the moment I am stuck after trying to start for about 20 times.

**Details:**

What is so peculiar is that

- The black screen does not always appear
- The black screen can appear at different stages of startup
- i) Directly after the BIOS (i.e., [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHqnP.jpg))
- ii) After I see the GRUB page and select to start Ubuntu (i.e., after
  [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOz0m.jpg))
- iii) After login to user account (instead of desktop I see the black screen - this only happens after having restarted from recovery mode)
- Often a normal startup would work after having booted once in recovery mode - but not always

What is additionally peculiar is that the startup process does not always look the same

- First screen: BIOS is always the first screen I see
- Second screen: Sometimes this is the GRUB menu, where I can select
  between different Ubuntu kernel versions / recovery mode etc
- Second screen: Sometimes I do not see GRUB and instead I directly see
  the purple screen of Ubuntu asking me for the password for full disk
  encryption (i.e., this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i78QE.jpg))

**What I have tried:**

- Clean reinstall of Ubuntu (problem persists)
- Pressing Esc on black screen (no effect)
- Pressing Ctrl+Alt F1 / F2 at black screen (no effect)
- I don’t have an Nvidia graphics card, so the Nvidia drivers should not be an issue (which is something many “black screen start problems” refer to)
- The computer is not a Dell, so the “solution” of changing the BIOS PPT security settings does not apply

**Hardware & software information:**

- Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon, Gen 4
- Graphics card: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
- Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, with full disk encryption
  enabled
- Gnome version 3.36.8

**Logs:**
Logs from journalctl -b -1 show me the following over and over again (but I cannot make sense of this":

```
Feb 22 17:31:22 This-Lenovo kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 2 callbacks suppressed

Feb 22 17:31:22 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011481.997:9571): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:22 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011481.997:9572): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:22 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:22 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:23 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011482.997:9573): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:23 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011482.997:9574): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:23 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:23 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:24 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011483.997:9575): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:24 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011483.997:9576): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:24 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:25 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011484.997:9577): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:25 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011484.997:9578): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:24 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:25 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:25 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:26 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011485.997:9579): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:26 This-Lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1614011485.997:9580): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:26 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:26 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:27 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/netstat" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Feb 22 17:31:27 This-Lenovo audit[1228]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo" name="/proc/1228/net/snmp" pid=1228 comm="ftdc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Comment: Would it ever do this when booting on a Live CD or USB?

Comment: Yes I also had the problem when re-installing ubuntu form a live USB

Comment: @ohiovr Are there any logs I could try to find to triangulate what the problem is?

Comment: Well what I mean is, before installing is the Live Enviroment pretty stable with video? In Ubuntu Mate there is a Log file viewer. You can click on your menu button and type in Log viewer. In there you may find the log file in question. Syslog maybe the one you are after. You can search for "error" to find your issue faster.

Comment: @Ohiovr the black screen only appears during boot. IF I manage to actually log in, the system is stable - both if booted by live USB / in the live environment and if booted in normal install. HOWEVER, the problem is that logging in / booting does not work. And for the boot process it doesn't matter if I try to boot from a live USB, the black screen still appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately managed to solve the issue by updating the bios (from legacy to uefi and then to latest version).

Answer (score 0):

I found that pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key generally solves this on a Lenovo.

Comment: There is no effect of pressing Esc key when the blakc screen appears